# How to disconnect from wifi on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, wifi, ui

How does one disconnect from a wifi hotspot on Mac OS X?

The only way I found how is to *Turn Wi-Fi off* then back on and finally select a different access point...

Surely there must be a better way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hold down the option key when you click on the WiFi menu. Then next to the currently active network there will be a "Disconnect from" option. I'm on Yosemite, and so I'm not sure whether this was present on earlier versions of OS X.

[image]

Comment: I'm on Yosemite too so will not comment on that part. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The disconnect option is not available in Lion.

Comment: FYI, the Disconnect option is not available on Mavericks either. This has to be the most stupid design I've ever seen. Ended up disabling `Remember networks this computer has joined` in the Wifi options.

Comment: Mine immediately reconnects after selecting 'disconnect'.

Comment: Directly hit on the bull's eye... Thanks for the answer

Comment: In Big Sur, 11.4, there does not seem to be an explicit "Disconnect" choice, but clicking on the selected hotspot in the menu has the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use Terminal:

Instead of "DEVICE_NAME" use your interface (i.g.: en0)

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport "DEVICE_NAME" -z
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on Big Sur which does not, AFAICT, have a “disconnect” option.