# When did this option in the WiFi network selection appear?

Tags: mac, wifi, high-sierra

I don't recall seeing this option before in the WiFi network selection. Is it configurable?

OS X version 10.13.4

[image: WiFi Network Select Dropdown]

Comment: it was always there, when you hold option key and click on WiFi icon

Comment: I've seen it since (at least) Mavericks, but what do you mean "is it configurable?"  What do you wan it to do besides disconnect?

Comment: A quick search shows that the option-click version must have been introduced with Yosemite: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156899/how-to-disconnect-from-wifi-on-mac-os-x  http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/19/disconnect-wi-fi-network-mac/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In High Sierra when you Hold the Option key and click on the WiFi Icon it will show you this.

The Disconnect from (current WiFi) shows when you use the Option key.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, holding option shows it with all the additional network info, but just the "Disconnect from NETWORK" line is showing up when I click it with no other keys pressed.

Comment: Ok, so tell us what kind of WiFi are you using, who's,who s the provider

Comment: It's my home wifi, from an Asus router. I found that the bug happens while connected to my 2.4Ghz network, but not when connected to my 5Ghz.

Comment: @Aaron It's not a bug, it's a feature (see my answer for an attempt to explain).

Answer (score 0):

In High Sierra (and Mojave), if you de-select...
**Automatically join this network**
...in `System Preferences > Network`, just beneath the Network Name selection, the "disconnect from -network name-" option will be visible, when single clicking the Wi-Fi menu bar item and when clicking the "Network Name" in the Network preference panel.

This seems new to High Sierra.

In Sierra and before all known networks were joined automatically, with no way to differentiate between e.g. the 5 GHz and the 2.4 GHz known network and with the latter often synced from another device, which was not desired.
The Mac then frequently connected to the 2.4 GHz network (which usually gets discovered first), instead of the 5 GHz one.

---

An "**Auto-Join**" check box is new in Mojave.

To configure: the possibility to disconnect (without pressing the option key) only appears, if you do not tick "auto-join" for your network.

For the menu bar item to show the option to disconnect, when single clicked, go to...

```
System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Wi-Fi > Preferred Networks
```

...and un-tick the "Auto-Join" check box next to one of the preferred networks.

If the "Auto-Join" check box is ticked, the option to disconnect will disappear in the menu bar item.

Presumably this feature is meant to make it easier to disconnect from public Wi-Fi spots, like airports and what have you, which you usually wouldn't want to auto-join.